# Print python database query to HTML document

Tags: python, sql, oracle, web

I wrote some python to query an Oracle database and I would like it to print the results in a formatted HTML table when I look at it with my browser.  I am unsure how to do this.

The python I wrote is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
import imp,datetime
import cx_Oracle

def index():
   conn_str = u'$USERNAME/$PASSWORD@$HOSTNAME:$PORT/$SERVICENAME'
   conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
   c = conn.cursor()
   query = c.execute(u'SELECT $FIELD1, $FIELD2, $FIELD3 FROM $TABLE')
   cur = c.fetchall()
   for row in cur:
      print(str(row))


   conn.close()
```

A co-worker of mine has a similar script he wrote that is immensely more complicated in terms of credentialing and cursor creation, and he uses the "write" in Python to output.  With his I can at least get output to a webpage, and I can't understand why mine won't even show anything, let alone my query results.  The problem is that his output comes out unformatted and even if I used his code I don't know how to give it table structure.

For contrast, his:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
import os
os.environ["ORACLE_BASE"]="/oracle"
os.environ["ORACLE_HOME"]="/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1"
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]="/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib:/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/dbjava/lib"
os.environ["TNS_ADMIN"]="/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/network/admin"
import imp,datetime
import cx_Oracle

DBCONNECTED=""
CONNECT={}

def connect(tnsname):
   global DBCONNECTED
   DB={}
   DB['$DATABASE']=['$USER','$PASSWORD']

   #print str(DB[tnsname][0]+"/"+DB[tnsname][1]+"@"+tnsname)
   conn=cx_Oracle.connect(DB[tnsname][0]+"/"+DB[tnsname][1]+"@"+tnsname)
   DBCONNECTED+=tnsname+":"
   return conn

def getcredentials(env,user):
   env=env.lower()
   CRED={};CRED['$DATABASENAME']={};
   CRED['$DATABASENAME']['$USERNAME']='$PASSWORD'
   if env in CRED and user in CRED[env]:
      return CRED[env][user]
   else:
      return 'ERR'

def returnconnection(dbtns):
   global CONNECT
   if DBCONNECTED.find(dbtns+":")==-1: #connection hasn't been initialized, do that
      CONNECT[dbtns]=connect(dbtns.lower())
   cur= CONNECT[dbtns].cursor()
   return cur

def runq(dbtns,query,bindvar=''):
   query=query.replace("\n"," ")
   cur=returnconnection(dbtns)
   if bindvar=='':
      cur.execute(query)
   else:
      cur.execute(query,bindvar)

   rs=cur.fetchall() #this should be fine for up to several thousand rows
   return rs

def index (req,rssid=""):
   global R; R=req; R.content_type="text/html"
   R.write("""
      <!DOCTYPE HTML">
      <html><head><title>TABLES</title><META HTTP-EQUIV='Pragma' CONTENT='no-cache'>
      </head>
      <table>
   """)
   dat=runq('$DATABASE','SELECT $FIELD1, $FIELD2, $FIELD3 FROM $TABLE')

   for row in dat:
      R.write(str(row))


   #write footer
   R.write("""
   </table>
   </body></html>
   """)
```

I like the simplicity of what I wrote, but my colleague is obviously doing something right to spit the output to a page.  When I try and re-create his usage of "Global R" to invoke "R.write" I get a unicode error regarding the content_type module, which seems odd.

Regardless, I feel this should be insanely simple.  I'm more used to PHP, and this is my first attempt at using Python to create this sort of webpage.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use unicode strings? Your colleague doesn't. Try without the "u" prefix on your strings.

Comment: I recognized that might be an issue, so I did try without.  I still get an attribute error when trying to mirror his use of "R.write" however.  This time it says that the 'str' object has to attribute 'content_type'

Comment: Just went back...by jove I think I've got it...at least the getting my query to display in the browser piece.  I was missing a u in the connection string.  Now I just have to figure out how to format it.  I can list it table-wise, but the results show up as string-rows like ('AA','text',36,36) and so on.  I'm not sure how to split the elements and print them in tablature.